# Timeout with system search

Tags: powershell

I run a short script to delete a couple of local files from a list of systems in a text file.  The issue is that when the script runs, if the system is not alive on the network, the script hangs for what seems like an eternity.  Is there a way to shorten the query time so that the script can skip the inactive system and continue on to the next one in line?

```
function delete-remotefile {
PROCESS {
            $file = "\\$_\c$\Windows\folderx\filename.txt"
            if (test-path $file)
            {
            echo "$_ filename.txt exists"
            Remove-Item $file -force
            echo "$_ filename.txt file deleted"
            }
            $file = "\\$_\c$\Windows\folderx\filename2.txt"
            if (test-path $file)
            {
            echo "$_ filename2.txt exists"
            Remove-Item $file -force
            echo "$_ filename2.txt file deleted"
            }
        }
}

Get-Content  C:\Users\username\Desktop\systems.txt | delete-remotefile

pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid execution on systems that are not available, simply wrap your command in `Test-Connection` . This will only execute if the system is available.

**Ex:**

```
function delete-remotefile {
PROCESS {

            if(Test-Connection $_)
            {
                $file = "\\$_\c$\Windows\folderx\filename.txt"
                if (test-path $file)
                {
                echo "$_ filename.txt exists"
                Remove-Item $file -force
                echo "$_ filename.txt file deleted"
                }
                $file = "\\$_\c$\Windows\folderx\filename2.txt"
                if (test-path $file)
                {
                echo "$_ filename2.txt exists"
                Remove-Item $file -force
                echo "$_ filename2.txt file deleted"
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Awesome - Thanks!

Comment: I set the if (test-Connection $_ -quiet)

Comment: `-quiet` will force it to return only a boolean. Normally, if I dont want any output from `test-connection`   I will do: `if(Test-Connection $_ -Quiet -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null)`. If you are really curious about all your options. [Here is documentation from MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Thanks for the help - much appreciation.

Comment: Another Test-Connection note: to make it a touch faster, you can specify -count 1 so it sends a single packet. Else, you have to wait for the default four failed packets before it evaluates. When the host is unreachable, that can take quite a while.